How to change time on ubuntu 22.04?
I change the time using timedatectl set-time command, but for some reason it reverts to the previous value after a few seconds.

This issue will be a consequence of choices made in Settings > Date & Time where Automatic Date & Time and Automatic Time Zone are set as shown below.
Change these settings at will to suit your requirement.


You can use the date command with -s or --set . You may need the root privilege .
Example
sudo date -s "2024-09-06 18:00:00"

or
sudo date --set="2024-09-06 18:00:00"

Also you can set the time part only. e.g
sudo date -s "18:00:00"
sudo date --set="18:00:00"

You may also use rdate command to set the system's date from a remote host
Please read the man page of the rdate command
